# Nginx Active/Active Cluster Setup

Tags: nginx, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I am currently attempting to configure a pair of load balancing servers in an Active/Active configuration using the following:

1. Nginx
2. Corosync
3. Pacemaker

Applicable instructions were followed according to [Clusters from Scratch](http://www.clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/).

However I do not know if the cluster is running in Active-Active configuration based upon the following crm_mon output. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
============
Last updated: Mon Oct 29 16:58:32 2012
Last change: Mon Oct 29 11:06:38 2012 via cibadmin on test2
Stack: openais
Current DC: test2 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.7-6.el6-148fccfd5985c5590cc601123c6c16e966b85d14
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
2 Resources configured.
============

Online: [ test2 test ]

 Clone Set: ClusterIP_clone [ClusterIP] (unique)
     ClusterIP:0    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started test
     ClusterIP:1    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started test2
```

This is the corosync.conf file:

```
compatibility: whitetank

aisexec {
    user: root
    group: root
}

service {
    name: pacemaker
    ver: 0
}

totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    crypto_cipher: none
    crypto_hash: none
    cluster_name: gmotest
    interface {
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.0.3
        }
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.0.4
        }
        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 192.168.0.0
        mcastport: 5405
        ttl: 1
    }
    transport: udpu
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_logfile: yes
    to_syslog: yes
    debug: on
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    debug: off
    timestamp: on
    logger_subsys {
            subsys: AMF
            debug: off
    }
}

amf {
     mode: disabled
}
```

Commands executed:

```
configure property stonith-enabled=false
configure primitive ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip=192.168.0.2 cidr_netmask=24 clusterip_hash="sourceip" op monitor interval=30s    
cib new active
configure clone ClusterIP_clone ClusterIP meta globally-unique="true" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="2"
cib commit active
```